# node.js - unable to install tcpsocket-serialport

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, npm, serial-port

I'm currently trying to set up my ESP8266 with Johnny Five wirelessly via node.js. To do this I need to get a virtual Serial Port via TCP. I found a very promising node-module but i just can't get it to install. I've been browsing the web for quite some time now. I installed the windows 8.1 SDK including c++ compiler, the windows build tools, node-gyp (which was basically the reason for all the other stuff) but now I'm completely stuck as I don't know what to make of the errors.

This is where I got the pacakage from

https://github.com/sizuhiko/tcpsocket-serialport

These are the errors (sorry for the mess)

```
 Die Projekte in dieser Projektmappe werden nacheinander erstellt. Um eine parallele Erstellung zu ermöglichen, müssen Sie den Schalter "/m" hinzufügen.
      serialport.cpp
      serialport_win.cpp
      enumser.cpp
      win_delay_load_hook.cc
    ..\src\win\enumser.cpp(443): warning C4996: 'GetVersionExA': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\P
    rogrammieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\
    serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(433): note: see declaration of 'GetVersionExA
      '
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(263): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)': function template has alread
    y been defined (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduin
    o\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\nan\nan.h(256): note: see declaration of '_NanEnsureLocal' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport
      .cpp)
    c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(2123): warning C4311: 'reinterpret_cast': pointer truncation from 'const
     void *' to 'unsigned long' (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmier
    en\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport
    .vcxproj]
      c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(2117): note: while compiling class template member function 'bool CS
      tdStr<wchar_t>::TryLoad(const void *)' (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp)
      c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(2171): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool
      CStdStr<wchar_t>::TryLoad(const void *)' being compiled (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp)
      c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(3982): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'CStdStr<
      wchar_t>' being compiled (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp)
    c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(2123): warning C4302: 'reinterpret_cast': truncation from 'const void *'
     to 'unsigned long' (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\
    arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj
    ]
    c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(2126): warning C4311: 'reinterpret_cast': pointer truncation from 'const
     void *' to 'unsigned long' (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmier
    en\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport
    .vcxproj]
    c:\users\chris\onedrive\programmieren\code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\src\win\stdstring.h(2126): warning C4302: 'reinterpret_cast': truncation from 'const void *'
     to 'unsigned long' (compiling source file ..\src\win\enumser.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\
    arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj
    ]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (compiling sour
    ce file ..\src\serialport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialpor
    t\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2039: 'FreeCallback': is not a member of 'node' (compiling source file ..\src\se
    rialport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\jo
    hnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_object_wrap.h(8): note: see declaration of 'node' (compiling
       source file ..\src\serialport.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FreeCallback' (compiling source file ..\src\seri
    alport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\john
    ny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'callback': undeclared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\serialport
    .cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-fiv
    e\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'hint': undeclared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp
    ) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\no
    de_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(672): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argumen
    t types (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\te
    st2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_buffer.h(46): note: could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> nod
      e::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate *,char *,std::size_t)' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp)
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_buffer.h(34): note: or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> nod
      e::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.
      cpp)
      C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\nan\nan.h(672): note: while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *, const char *, uint32
      _t)' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(676): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v
    8::Object>' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\j
    f\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\nan\nan.h(676): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution
       was ambiguous (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C2039: 'Use': is not a member of 'node::Buffer' (compiling source file ..\src\ser
    ialport.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\joh
    nny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_buffer.h(11): note: see declaration of 'node::Buffer' (compi
      ling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found (compiling source file ..\src\serialport.cpp)
    [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node
    _modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(263): error C2995: 'v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)': function template has alread
    y been defined (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\ar
    duino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\nan\nan.h(256): note: see declaration of '_NanEnsureLocal' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport
      _win.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C3083: 'smalloc': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type (compiling sour
    ce file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-seria
    lport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2039: 'FreeCallback': is not a member of 'node' (compiling source file ..\src\se
    rialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_module
    s\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_object_wrap.h(8): note: see declaration of 'node' (compiling
       source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(661): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FreeCallback' (compiling source file ..\src\seri
    alport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\
    johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'callback': undeclared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\serialport
    _win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny
    -five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(665): error C2065: 'hint': undeclared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win
    .cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-fiv
    e\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(672): error C2665: 'node::Buffer::New': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argumen
    t types (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\j
    f\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_buffer.h(46): note: could be 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> nod
      e::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate *,char *,std::size_t)' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp)
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_buffer.h(34): note: or       'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> nod
      e::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate *,v8::Local<v8::String>,node::encoding)' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_
      win.cpp)
      C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\nan\nan.h(672): note: while trying to match the argument list '(v8::Isolate *, const char *, uint32
      _t)' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(676): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v
    8::Object>' (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\ardui
    no\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\nod
      e_modules\nan\nan.h(676): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution
       was ambiguous (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C2039: 'Use': is not a member of 'node::Buffer' (compiling source file ..\src\ser
    ialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules
    \johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\chris\.node-gyp\4.6.1\include\node\node_buffer.h(11): note: see declaration of 'node::Buffer' (compi
      ling source file ..\src\serialport_win.cpp)
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\nan\nan.h(683): error C3861: 'Use': identifier not found (compiling source file ..\src\serialport_win.c
    pp) [C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\
    node_modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(152): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users
    \chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\
    serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(152): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\chris\O
    neDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialpo
    rt\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(177): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(179): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(183): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(185): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(189): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(191): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(196): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(208): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(308): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users
    \chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\
    serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(308): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\chris\O
    neDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialpo
    rt\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(318): warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users
    \chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\
    serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(318): warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\chris\O
    neDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialpo
    rt\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(328): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(353): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(366): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(401): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(403): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(502): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    ..\src\serialport_win.cpp(511): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [
    C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_
    modules\serialport\build\serialport.vcxproj]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:285:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\chris\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\chris\\OneDrive\\Programmieren\\Code\\arduino\\jf\\test2\\tcpsocket-serialport\\node_modules\\johnny-five\\node_modules\\serialport\\build\\serialport\\v1.7.4\\Release\\node-v46-win32-x64\\serialport.node" "--module_name=serialport" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\chris\\OneDrive\\Programmieren\\Code\\arduino\\jf\\test2\\tcpsocket-serialport\\node_modules\\johnny-five\\node_modules\\serialport\\build\\serialport\\v1.7.4\\Release\\node-v46-win32-x64"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport\v1.7.4\Release\node-v46-win32-x64\serialport.node --module_name=serialport --module_path=C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport\v1.7.4\Release\node-v46-win32-x64' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\chris\\OneDrive\\Programmieren\\Code\\arduino\\jf\\test2\\tcpsocket-serialport\\node_modules\\johnny-five\\node_modules\\serialport\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.7
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport\v1.7.4\Release\node-v46-win32-x64\serialport.node --module_name=serialport --module_path=C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport\node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport\build\serialport\v1.7.4\Release\node-v46-win32-x64' (1)
    tcpsocket-serialport@0.1.0 C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Programmieren\Code\arduino\jf\test2\tcpsocket-serialport
    +-- del@1.2.1
    | +-- each-async@1.1.1
    | | +-- onetime@1.1.0
...
      |   +-- string_decoder@1.0.1
      |   | `-- safe-buffer@5.0.1  deduped
      |   `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2  deduped
      `-- jsdoctypeparser@1.2.0
        `-- lodash@3.10.1

    npm WARN tcpsocket-serialport@0.1.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: serialport@1.7.4 (node_modules\johnny-five\node_modules\serialport):
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: serialport@1.7.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Another package i found was this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-serial

Sadly it says ist tcp but if you try the given example it just gives you the error message, that it only works with udp. Anyways, if someone had an idea how to get either of those 2 running I'd be really thankful. I will still be trying to solve it by myself to and be sure to post an answer if I find one. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the mistake was pretty obvious once I took a look in the package.json.

The problem was I already included johnny-five in a parent folder which led to a conflict here. So if anyone happens to stumble over the same problem, don't install johnny five and try to install tcpsocket-serialport afterwards.